# Rtab map stereo visual odometry pose scale?

Tags: slam, navigation, visual-odometry, ros-melodic, rtabmap-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm kind of new to ROS, I'm trying to use the stereo visual odometry of RTAB map to produce odometry for localization, I have tried it on gazebo, the pose in the odom topic is translated in gazebo as one grid cell, what i don't understand is what is the ground truth for the pose when using real stereo camera? is it 1 meter for every change in X or Y? and how can i specify the unit of the pose?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349667/rtab-map-stereo-visual-odometry-pose-scale?/) by [3bkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/53649/3bkr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will be the units used during the calibration of the stereo camera (checkboard size). In general, the units will be in meters.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [3bkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/53649/3bkr/) on 2020-04-18**:
Thank youu

**Comment by [3bkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/53649/3bkr/) on 2020-04-19**:
Hello again, I have tried using a stereo camera and i have a problem, the scale is not logical on high speed, i have tried moving in a straight line in the X direction for 100 meters on a speed 40 km/h and it gives not logical numbers, is that normal or I have a problem?
Thanks in advance

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-04-21**:
It could be a tracking problem, but units should always be the same. What kind of camera do you use? If the cameras are not synchronized, it may affect the scale when moving.

**Comment by [3bkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/53649/3bkr/) on 2020-05-05**:
Hello thanks alot for your reply
What do you mean by tracking problem?
I’m using two synchronized leopard imaging cameras for stereo and for the calibration i used the camera calibration package

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-05-12**:
If visual odometry fails to or wrongly match features, it could create wrong transformations. Maybe I didn't understand what you mean by "it gives not logical numbers".

**Comment by [3bkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/53649/3bkr/) on 2020-05-12**:
Sorry i meant the result is not logical, for example i drive for 100 meters in a straight line so the X in pose is supposed to be 100 in the odom topic but the result is 2

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-05-13**:
do you have a database to share?